# Using environment specific group/host_vars and mapping to var subdirectories in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm having issues finding good documentation for how to use environment specific (i.e. dev & test) group_vars and host_vars, then map down to subdirectories that are specific to large chunks of infrastructure (the wso2 directories).

Ideally, I should be able to say somewhere in my inventory or playbook `dev` or `test` and it should just route to `dev` or `test` then specify `wso2` and have it look there.

```
.
├── group_vars
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── wso2
│   │       ├── apim-analytics.yml
│   │       ├── apim-is-as-km.yml
│   │       └── apim.yml
│   └── test
│       └── wso2
│           ├── apim-analytics.yml
│           ├── apim-is-as-km.yml
│           └── apim.yml
├── host_vars
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── wso2
│   │       ├── apim-analytics-dashboard_1.yml
│   │       ├── apim-analytics-worker_1.yml
│   │       ├── apim-gateway_1.yml
│   │       ├── apim-is-as-km_1.yml
│   │       ├── apim-km_1.yml
│   │       ├── apim-publisher_1.yml
│   │       ├── apim-store_1.yml
│   │       ├── apim-tm_1.yml
│   │       ├── wso2-apim-01.yml
│   │       └── wso2-apim-02.yml
│   └── test
│       └── wso2
│           ├── apim-analytics-dashboard_1.yml
│           ├── apim-analytics-worker_1.yml
│           ├── apim-gateway_1.yml
│           ├── apim-is-as-km_1.yml
│           ├── apim-km_1.yml
│           ├── apim-publisher_1.yml
│           ├── apim-store_1.yml
│           ├── apim-tm_1.yml
│           ├── wso2-apim-01.yml
│           └── wso2-apim-02.yml
```

There is great documentation about all other subjects around ansible... just not this, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks all :)

Comment: What's your goal exactly? Have you checked on this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manage-multistage-environments-with-ansible